# URL Redirect from text file

Tags: python

I'm still pretty new to scripting. I'm trying to figure out a way to output a list of URL after the redirect has occurred. I have about 800 sites in a text file that I want to test for a redirect using a python script and output the final redirect to a file (on it's own line). Is this possible?

With the file open, I can't figure out how to make urllib2.urlopen() read a line in a text file. It seems to require a URL? Maybe there is another module or something else I should be using instead?

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code that you have so far! :-)

Comment: As the name implies, `urllib2.urlopen()` opens a URL, returning a `file`-like object; it doesn't read a line from a text file. So please show us your code and we'll help you fix it. FWIW, I'd probably just use `urllib.urlopen()` for a task like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

```
import requests

with open('urls.txt') as url_file:
    for url in url_file:
        resp = requests.get(url.strip())
        print resp.url
```

Comment: +1 for requests. Simple, elegant and awesome. OP, please use this method instead!